# Is there a standard POSIX symbol for ignoring words in a sentence?

Tags: r, posix

**Is there is a standard POSIX symbol that allows you to ignore certain words a sentence?**

For example, consider the following.

```
(x <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))
# [1] "2014-11-03 08:24:39 PST"
fmt <- "Today is %A, %B %d %Y.\nThe time is %R and %S seconds."
cat(f <- format(x, fmt))
# Today is Monday, November 03 2014.
# The time is 08:24 and 39 seconds.
```

Now I'd like to reverse this process, using `f` to return an object identical to `x`.
Hopefully the same way I created it.  However, I need to ignore a few words and so I though there might be a standard POSIX symbol to skip words in a formatted string.

I only know how to do this my manipulating the string with `grep` and `strsplit`. Here's what I am currently using to get my desired result.

```
s <- sapply(c(fmt, f), strsplit, "[,. ]", USE.NAMES = FALSE)
vp <- vapply(s, function(x) {
    paste(x[grep("[%]", s[[1]])], collapse = " ")
}, character(1))
strptime(vp[2], vp[1])
# [1] "2014-11-03 08:24:39 PST"
```

Which works. But, in `?strptime` I noticed that there are a few symbols for newlines and arbitrary whitespace in strings.  But I didn't see any that allow you to bypass 
words.

> `%n` - Newline on output, arbitrary whitespace on input.
>   `%t` - Tab on output, arbitrary whitespace on input.

**Does there exist a POSIX standard symbol for skipping a word or phrase?**
And is there a better method for this type of operation?

To further clarify, I would like to go from

```
> f
 [1] "Today is Monday, November 03 2014.\nThe time is 08:24 and 39 seconds."
```

back to the `POSIXct` object

```
 [1] "2014-11-03 08:24:39 PST"
```

using only `strptime` and/or `format`, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
> as.POSIXct(f, format = fmt)
[1] "2014-11-03 12:06:40 EST"
```

If you are trying to extract the components using only string operations then we could use `.*` to match junk:

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "(\\w+) (\\d+) (\\d+).* (\\d+):(\\d+) .* (\\d+)"
strapplyc(f, pat, simplify = c)
## [1] "November" "03"       "2014"     "12"       "06"       "40"
```

or

```
pat2 <- ".* (\\w+) (\\d+) (\\d+).* (\\d+):(\\d+) .* (\\d+).*"
gsubfn(pat2, "\\3-\\1-\\2 \\4:\\5:\\6", f)
## [1] "2014-November-03 12:06:40"
```

Comment: Okay, yeah.  Now I'm a bit embarrassed.  But in general, is there a symbol that would allow me to skip over some words?

Comment: Did it intentionally drop `"Monday"`, or do we need an optional comma in there?

Comment: We don't need the day of the week to make the date time unique so I ignored that. Change `pat` or `pat2` appropriately if you want that too. (In the second case the replacement string would also have to be changed.)